# How to select all records where Timestamp date > or < other Timestamps?

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax-error

Compare 
`Timestamp pubDate = rs.getTimestamp("pubDate");`
with all other Timestamps in table by this query:

```
get * from items where pubDate<?
```

Throws the error:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'get * from items where 
pubDate<'2015-05-04 18:26:00'' at line 1
```

What is the right syntax?

Comment: `SELECT * FROM ...`  not `get`...

Comment: Not to sound harsh, but this is very basic SQL stuff (`SELECT` for queries). Please consider grabbing a SQL tutorial and working through it.

Comment: My bad.Sry for obvious question like this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SQL syntax used to retrieve rows from a table is `select`, not `get`:

```
SLEECT * FROM items WHERE pubDate < ?
```